# How to get image link from description tag

Tags: android

I would like to get the image link from the description tag of my rss feed.

the description tag is in the following format:

```
<description>&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href="http://feedads.g.doubleclick.net/~a/QVSgisNFiHp7mXgpD309loKdAQo/0/da"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feedads.g.doubleclick.net/~a/QVSgisNFiHp7mXgpD309loKdAQo/0/di" border="0" ismap="true"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
&lt;a href="http://feedads.g.doubleclick.net/~a/QVSgisNFiHp7mXgpD309loKdAQo/1/da"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feedads.g.doubleclick.net/~a/QVSgisNFiHp7mXgpD309loKdAQo/1/di" border="0" ismap="true"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on"&gt;&lt;a href="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-pogGG3n-PfM/TqoiXzjoTpI/AAAAAAAARKg/0OagMGCaddE/s1600/AA.jpg" style="font-family: Georgia, serif; font-size: 100%; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; line-height: normal;"&gt;&lt;span style="color: cyan;"&gt;&lt;img alt="" border="0" id="BLOGGER_PHOTO_ID_5668380873371176594" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-pogGG3n-PfM/TqoiXzjoTpI/AAAAAAAARKg/0OagMGCaddE/s320/AA.jpg" style="float: left; height: 320px; margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px; width: 320px;" /&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;div style="text-align: justify;"&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;09:15OTE Sport 2  Τένις ATP 250 Malaysia 1st semifinal&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;11:05OTE Sport 3  Moto GP ARAGON FP3&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;11:15OTE Sport 2  Τένις ATP 250 Malaysia 2nd semifinal&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;13:00NOVASPORTS 4  Ιστιοπλοΐα ALPARI 2012: World Match Racing Tour, Γαλλία&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;14:00OTE Sport 2  Γερμανία δεύτερη κατηγορία Μόναχο 1860-Σαντχάουζεν&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;14:45NOVASPORTS 1  Αγγλικό Πρωτάθλημα ΑΡΣΕΝΑΛ - ΤΣΕΛΣΙ&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;14:50OTE Sport 3  Moto GP ARAGON QUAL&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;15:00EUROSPORT  Ποδόσφαιρο: Παγκόσμιο Γυναικών U-17 Φάση ομίλων: Γκάμπια - Γαλλία&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;16:00NOVASPORTS 3  Φιλικός αγώνας μπάσκετ ΟΛΥΜΠΙΑΚΟΣ - ΛΟΚΟΜΟΤΙΒ ΚΟΥΜΠΑΝ&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;16:30OTE Sport 1  Γερμανικό Πρωτάθλημα Βέρντερ-Μπάγερν&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;17:00OTE Sport 3  Football League Παναιτωλικός-Καλλονή&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;17:00OTE Sport 2  Ισπανικό Πρωτάθλημα Βαλένθια-Σαραγόσα&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;17:00EUROSPORT  Ποδηλασία Γύρος της Λομβαρδίας&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;17:15NOVASPORTS 1  Σούπερ Λίγκα ΠΑΝΙΩΝΙΟΣ - ΑΕΚ&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;17:15NOVASPORTS 2  Σούπερ Λίγκα ΚΕΡΚΥΡΑ - ΟΦΗ&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;18:15EUROSPORT  Ποδόσφαιρο: Παγκόσμιο Γυναικών U-17 Φάση ομίλων: Καναδάς- Αζερμπαϊτζάν&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;19:00OTE Sport 1  Ισπανικό Πρωτάθλημα Μάλαγα-Μπέτις&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;19:00OTE Sport 2  Ιταλικό Πρωτάθλημα Πάρμα-Μίλαν&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;19:00NOVASPORTS 3  Φιλικός αγώνας μπάσκετ ΤΣΣΚΑ ΜΟΣΧΑΣ - ΖΑΛΓΚΙΡΙΣ ΚΑΟΥΝΑΣ&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;19:00Sport TV  Βελγικό πρωτάθλημα ΖΟΥΛΤΕ ΒΑΡΕΓΚΕΜ-ΑΝΤΕΡΛΕΧΤ&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;19:30OTE Sport 3  Γερμανικό Πρωτάθλημα Ντόρτμουντ-Γκλάντμπαχ&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;19:30NOVASPORTS 2  Σούπερ Λίγκα ΑΤΡΟΜΗΤΟΣ - ΟΛΥΜΠΙΑΚΟΣ&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;19:30NOVASPORTS 1  Αγγλικό Πρωτάθλημα ΜΑΝΤΣΕΣΤΕΡ Γ. - ΤΟΤΕΝΑΜ&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;21:00OTE Sport 1  Ισπανικό Πρωτάθλημα Σοσιεδάδ-Αθλέτικ Μπιλμπάο&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;21:45OTE Sport 2  Ιταλικό Πρωτάθλημα Γιουβέντους-Ρόμα&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;22:30NOVASPORTS 2  Πορτογαλικό Πρωτάθλημα ΡΙΟ ΑΒΕ - ΠΟΡΤΟ&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;23:00OTE Sport 1  Ισπανικό Πρωτάθλημα Σεβίλη-Μπαρτσελόνα &lt;/div&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="https://active.macromedia.com/flash/cabs/swflash.cab#version=3,0,0,11" height="87" width="690"&gt;&lt;param name="Movie" value="http://network.clickbanner.gr/42/13418/13028/"&gt;&lt;param name="quality" value="high"&gt;&lt;param name="Loop" value="true"&gt;&lt;param name="play" value="true"&gt;&lt;param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain"&gt;&lt;param name="FlashVars" value="clickTAG=http://network.clickbanner.gr/z/13028/CD13418/"&gt;&lt;param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF"&gt;&lt;embed src="http://network.clickbanner.gr/42/13418/13028/" flashvars="clickTAG=http://network.clickbanner.gr/z/13028/CD13418/" quality="high" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" name="Banner" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="https://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" align="middle" height="87" width="679"&gt;&lt;/embed&gt;&lt;/object&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;a href="http://network.clickbanner.gr/z/12699/CD13418/" target="_blank"&gt;&lt;img alt="" border="0" src="http://network.clickbanner.gr/42/13418/12699/" style="height: 82px; margin: 0 10px 10px 0; width: 674px;" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class="blogger-post-footer"&gt;&lt;img width='1' height='1' src='https://blogger.googleusercontent.com/tracker/4261359698446466108-6623338655004558006?l=olympiacos-blog.blogspot.com' alt='' /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/olympiacos-blogspot/xJVek/~4/I0JP9iZXKTc" height="1" width="1"/&gt;</description><media:thumbnail xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" url="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-pogGG3n-PfM/TqoiXzjoTpI/AAAAAAAARKg/0OagMGCaddE/s72-c/AA.jpg" height="72" width="72" />
```

i would like to get the

`http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-pogGG3n-PfM/TqoiXzjoTpI/AAAAAAAARKg/0OagMGCaddE/s1600/AA.jpg`

The way i m trying it is

```
 if (description.contains("div class=\"seperator\" ")){
                String imgg  = description.substring(description.indexOf("div class=\"seperator\""));
                String cleanUp = imgg.substring(0, imgg.indexOf(">")+1);//deixnei apo pou ksekina to keimeno
                imgg = imgg.substring(imgg.indexOf("a href=") + 5);
                int indexOf = imgg.indexOf("\"");
                if (indexOf==-1){
                    indexOf = imgg.indexOf("\"");
                }
                imgg = imgg.substring(0, indexOf);

                setImgLink(imgg);
            this.description = this.description.replace(cleanUp, "");
        }   else{   ....
```

but i m always getting the else statement.How can i fix it please??

thanks for your time

@juan  could i use something like this?

```
DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(description);

XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "//img";
Node imgNode = (Node) xpath.evaluate(expression, document, XPathConstants.NODE);

String imgg = imgNode.getAttribute("src");
```

Comment: Where is `class="seperator"` defined? I don't see it in your XML

Comment: this is the link please http://feeds.feedburner.com/olympiacos-blogspot/xJVek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be your only problem, but

```
"class=\"seperator\" "
```

has a typo, should be

```
"class=\"separator\" "
```

Also, using Regexp to parse XML is brittle unless you control the XML completely. Even then, you're better off using an XML parser/ XPath

The XPath you have is going to retrieve the first image in the document, are you sure that's what you want? You probably should use something more like

```
//div[@class='separator']/img
```

To get an attribute from the returned `Node`, use

```
 imgNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("src").getNodeValue()
```

Comment: i have tried it with xpath but its not working too.but maybe i'm not using it in the right way..i have posted the code in my question in order to check it!thanks for your time :)

Comment: @androidDe did you change `seperator`  to `separator`?

Comment: is the following line correct? String imgg = imgNode.getAttribute("src");

Comment: Yes, that is the correct code to retrieve the src attribute of the image tag

Comment: i m getting the error : The method getAttribute(String) is undefined for the type Node

Comment: Just look in the API for the right method http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html Looks pretty bad when you ask questions without trying to answer them yourself first. I think it's `node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("src").getNodeValue()`

Comment: i m getting the following errors : on line DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();-->
 Unhandled exception type ParserConfigurationException

Comment: Document document = builder.parse(description);-->
Unhandled exception type IOException

Comment: and   Node imgNode = (Node) xpath.evaluate(expression, document, XPathConstants.NODE);-->
Unhandled exception type XPathExpressionException

Comment: @androidDe I'm not going to figure out every single problem for you, sorry! This is not a "do my work for me" forum, it's a "I have a specific question" forum, I already answered three different questions

Comment: @androidDe It's OK to keep asking, but each question needs to be a separate question that focuses on a single aspect of a problem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17317/discussion-between-androidde-and-juan-mendes)